# Delphi, освобождение памяти по ссылке OleVariant

Tags: delphi, dll, com, ole

Немного предыстории - есть библиотека some_lib.dll (реализована в visual studio), с помощью regasm регистрирую и создаю библиотеку типов, которую позже импортирую в проект delphi с созданием wrapper-ов. В Delphi следующий код:

```
procedure DoSomething();
var
    _id: Integer;
    _class: TClass; // TClass - класс из файла-обертки библиотеки типов
    _obj: OleVariant; // ссылка на объект, созданный после вызова одной из функций dll
begin
    try
        _id := 123;
        _class := TClass.Create(nil);
        _obj := _class.GetObject(123); // создаем объект, возвращаем ссылку
        _class.TreatObject(_obj); // передаем ссылку в другой метод, обрабатываем объект
        _class.TreatObjectAgain(_obj); // передаем ссылку в третий метод, опять что-то с ним делаем
    finnaly
        _class.Free;
        // _obj ???
    end;
end;
```

Вопрос в следующем - как правильно освободить память, занятую _obj? Насколько я понимаю, объект останется в памяти после того, как функция завершит работу.

Comment: Не останется. Лень писать ответ, может у кого руки дойдут - тогда удалю комментарий. Если получаемый объект является COM-интерфейсом, да и вообще любым интерфейсом (скорее всего, так и есть), то подсчет его ссылок (`AddRef`/`Release`) идет автоматически и при нормальной реализации исходной dll на выходе из `DoSomething` он будет уничтожен, т.к. счетчик ссылок на него дойдет до 0. А вообще - FastMM и аналоги вам в руки :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OleVariant относится к автоуправляемым типам (так же как и Variant, String, AnsiString, WideString, UnicodeString, динамические массивы, интерфейсы). Это означает, что (грубо говоря) компилятор автоматически очистит переменную при выходе её из зоны видимости. Вручную освобождать такие переменные не следует, это строго необходимо только в следующих случаях:

1. Выгрузка DLL, в которой была выделена переменная, до момента, где происходит автоматическая очистка ([например](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2013/04/plugins-9.html) - см. "Подводный камень: смешивание ручного и автоматического управления временем жизни")
2. Освобождение динамической памяти, в которой размещена сама переменная (например, автоуправляемая переменная как поле записи с динамическим выделением через указатель)
3. Преждевременная очистка с целью уменьшения расхода памяти
4. Ручное управление временем жизни

Если в вашем коде возникают проблемы при работе с OleVariant (а равно и с другими автоуправляемыми типами), то это означает что вы допустили ошибку при ручном управлении. [Например](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2011/03/9.html). Или [такую](http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2013/04/plugins-9.html) (см. "Ошибка: возврат сложных типов через Result"). Но это **не** означает, что вы забыли освободили память, как это могло бы быть для неуправляемых классов/объектов.

В любом случае, любые переменные автоуправляемых типов всегда можно очистить вручную в любой момент времени вызвав для них [Finalize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Finalize).